# php removing an element from objects

Tags: php

So, I have following db result:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [user] => 1           
        [img] => 2016/02/img_8488.jpg
        [url] => /p=?44           
        [sent_date] => 2016-02-13 00:00:00
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [user] => 185                     
        [img] => 
        [url] => /?p=54         
        [sent_date] => 2016-02-06 00:00:00
    )
```

)

How would I remove `[id]` and `[sent_date]` from the query result?

I am not sure if I am using unset right.

```
unset($results[0]['id']); 
$reindex = array_values($results); 
$objectarray = $reindex;
```

Comment: `[id]` and `[sent_date]` are not keys, it's properties of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removal or unset you can create a new array;

```
$i = 0;
$newResult = array();
foreach($result as $value){
$newResult[$i]["user"] = $value->user;
$newResult[$i]["img"] = $value->img;
$newResult[$i]["url"] = $value->url;
$i++;
}

print_r($newResult);
```

`$newResult` will return the new array and your original array remains same you can use it if you need.

Or removal of indexes is must required than use unset inside the foreach loop as:

```
unset($value->id); 
unset($value->sent_date);
```

**Side note**:

Also keep in mind you can not use it as `$value["id"]` becuase its a property not an array index.

Answer (score 1):

Use `unset($results[0]->id);` and `unset($results[0]->sent_date)` instead and it should work. If you want to do this in all of the array objects:

```
for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($results); $i++)
{
    unset($results[$i]->id);
    unset($results[$i]->sent_date);

}
```

Comment: Ah, i see. Thank you for the clarification! =)